# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids' when calling the class of a certain module

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, attributeerror, kivymd

I have a created a camera module that works independently. When I try to integrate it with my other modules, it gives me an error of AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'. I have a python file that handles the screen of my program and I have a camera python file which displays the camera on the interface.

I imported the Camera python file in my Screen python file and created an object for the classes of the Camera file. However, whenever I try to run the code, an error occurs.

Here are some portions of my code

**Screen.py:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import TouchBehavior
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader 
from plyer import vibrator
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import Camera as wc
import numpy as np
import pyttsx3
import time
import cv2
import socket


obj = wc.MyApp()
obj2 = wc.AndroidCamera()
obj3 = wc.MyLayout()
Window.size = (400, 700)

...

class TextToSpeechScreen(Screen):

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.ox < touch.x:
            self.manager.current = 'vibrate'
            print("Entering Camera")
            obj.build()
            obj.on_start()
            obj.get_frame(5)
            obj.recognition()
            
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):        
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            self.manager.current = 'feedback'
```

**Camera.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket

Builder.load_file('myapplayout.kv')

class AndroidCamera(Camera):
    camera_resolution = (640, 480)
    cam_ratio = camera_resolution[0] / camera_resolution[1]

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    ...

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

    def on_start(self):
        self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))
        data = self.s.recv(1024).decode()

        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_frame, 5)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.recognition, 20)

    def get_frame(self, dt):
        cam = self.root.ids.a_cam
        image_object = cam.export_as_image(scale=round((400 / int(cam.height)), 2))
        w, h = image_object._texture.size
        frame = np.frombuffer(image_object._texture.pixels, 'uint8').reshape(h, w, 4)
        self.gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_frame, 0.25)

    def recognition(self, *args):
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**myapplayout.kv:**

```
<MyLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: root.width, root.height

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2

        RelativeLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.8

            AndroidCamera:
                index: 0
                id: a_cam
                resolution: self.camera_resolution
                allow_stretch: True
                play: True
                canvas.before:
                    PushMatrix
                    Rotate:
                        angle: -90
                        origin: self.center
                    Scale:
                        x: self.cam_ratio
                        y: self.cam_ratio
                        origin: self.center
                canvas.after:
                    PopMatrix

        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            id: frame_counter
            font_size: self.height * 0.4
            text: ''
```

I don't know why it's giving me an error, but it works perfectly fine back then when I didn't integrate it with the other module that I have. The error points at the first line of the get_frame function under the Camera.py file.

Comment: Just to simplify troubleshooting could you consider replacing AndroidCamera with a BoxLayout and just something simple inside it like a Label.  It could narrow down if you have a problem with the Camera module or if this is a Kivy  or Python problem.

I don't usually use the .ids but I think you are expecting self to be the app and root to be MyLayout so it makes sense this * should * work.